# Aligment of the hightlight in the TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create TikZ diagram to represent the HDD platter. On the platter the track, sector and blocks should be highlighted. I moved from the simple by-the-hand calculated render more onto the systematic approach using variables and calculations and it almost works. ***The problem I have is with the matching of the lines drawn before the "highlighter" takes action*** (as shown in the picture bellow). Fumbling with the values little bit I found comibination which is usabe for my usecase, I still wonder and cannot figure out, where does the misalignment comes from.

PS.: I'm using Overleaf to write and render TeX files.

TikZ HDD schematic:

```
% Hard disk drive platter
% Author: Tomáš Michalek
%
% This diagram attempts to create HDD platter with the selectable track,
% sector and block highlighting.
%
% Current version is quite fragile and any improvements are welcome
%
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}


\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   CUSTOMISATIONS
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\numTracks{8}      
\def\numSectors{12}

\def\selectedTrack{6}  % Track to highlight, negative values disable the selection
\def\selectedSector{0} % Sector to highlight, negative values disable the selection

\definecolor{baseColor}{RGB}{18, 54, 69}        % Basic lines and borders
\definecolor{accentColor}{RGB}{1, 103, 143}     % Selection
\definecolor{highlightColor}{RGB}{221, 109, 16} % Crossover of two selections


\pgfmathsetmacro\firstTrack{10cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastTrack{2cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   CALCULATIONS
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\trackStepRange}{\firstTrack-\lastTrack}
\pgfmathsetmacro\trackStep{\trackStepRange/\numTracks}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sectorStep{360/\numSectors}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\selectedSectorStart}{-\sectorStep*\selectedSector} % natural rotation
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\selectedBlockStart}{\firstTrack-\selectedTrack*\trackStep}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\selectedBlockEnd}{\selectedBlockStart-\trackStep}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   DRAWING
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Draw track lines
\foreach \track in {0,...,\numTracks} {
    \draw [baseColor!20] (0,0) circle (\firstTrack-\track*\trackStep);
}

% Draw sector lines
\foreach \i in {0, \sectorStep, ..., 359}
    \draw [baseColor!20] (\i:\firstTrack) -- (\i:\lastTrack);

\foreach \sector in {0, \sectorStep, ..., 359} {
    \pgfmathparse{mod(\sector, \sectorStep*2)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\remainder}{\pgfmathresult}
    
    \ifnum\remainder=0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sectorTint}{50};
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\sectorTint}{50}; %25
    \fi

    % If the `track` is selected, highlight it
    \ifnum\selectedTrack>-1
        \fill[accentColor!\sectorTint] (\sector:\selectedBlockStart) arc (\sector:\sector+\sectorStep:\selectedBlockStart) -- (\sector+\sectorStep:\selectedBlockEnd) arc (\sector+\sectorStep:\sector:\selectedBlockEnd) -- cycle;
    \fi
}

% If the `sector` is selected, highlight it
\ifnum\selectedSector>-1
    \fill[accentColor!30, rotate=\selectedSectorStart] (0:\firstTrack) arc (0:\sectorStep:\firstTrack) -- (\sectorStep:\lastTrack) arc (\sectorStep:0:\lastTrack) -- cycle;
\fi

% If both `sector` and `track` are selected, highlight `block`
\ifnum\selectedSector>-1
    \ifnum\selectedTrack>-1
        \fill[highlightColor!80, rotate=\selectedSectorStart] (0:\selectedBlockStart) arc (0:\sectorStep:\selectedBlockStart) -- (\sectorStep:\selectedBlockEnd) arc (\sectorStep:0:\selectedBlockEnd) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aligment issue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the units `cm` from your macros `\firstTrack` and `\lastTrack` your diagram will be drawn more correct. The size is different now but that can be adjusted again by [scaling](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#tikz/scale) the diagram or [changing the *xyz* vectors](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.2).

When you use units, these lengths will be converted to `pt`s and on which you use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. This will lead to a different result than with `\pgfmathsetmacro` and since you also don't use `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro`, the unit will be lost and the value will be interpreted to be in the *xyz*  coordinate system again which scales your diagram beyond the values (2cm, 10cm) you actually want.

---

In summary:

```
   input       converted

     2cm      56.9055 pt
    10cm     284.52756pt
10cm-2cm     227.62206pt
```

but with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` the value `227` will be stored in `\trackStepRange` which will then lead to `\trackStep` being wrong and then everything else that depends on it as well.

---

That said, I've rewritten your diagram because it was a bit too much for me to follow. It's the same approach, though, I believe, with the exception that I'm counting the tracks from inside to outside. This makes the math a bit easier.

---

I have also a draft of another approach where each block is drawn/filled individually and a few styles like `track 1 sector 0/.style=hdd sel block` are defined and accessed during two nested loops.

If you need to color/tint areas further that solution might be easier to use.

And we can also use the [`heatmark` shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693410).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\definecolor     {baseColor}{RGB}{ 18,  54,  69} % Basic lines and borders
\definecolor   {accentColor}{RGB}{  1, 103, 143} % Selection
\definecolor{highlightColor}{RGB}{221, 109,  16} % Crossover of two selections
\tikzset{
  ring segment/.style n args={4}{insert path={% helpful
       ({#1}:{#4}) arc[start angle={#1}, end angle={#2}, radius={#4}]
    -- ({#2}:{#3}) arc[start angle={#2}, end angle={#1}, radius={#3}] -- cycle}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  hdd border/.style    ={draw=     baseColor!20},
  hdd sel track/.style ={fill=   accentColor!50},
  hdd sel sector/.style={fill=   accentColor!30},
  hdd sel block/.style ={fill=highlightColor!80},
]
%% independent of selection
\newcommand*\numTracks{8}
\newcommand*\numSectors{12}
\newcommand*\baseR{2}
\newcommand*\stepR{.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\maxR{\baseR+\numTracks*\stepR}
\pgfmathsetmacro\stepAngle{360/\numSectors}

%% dependent of selection
\newcommand*\selTrack{1}
\newcommand*\selSector{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\selAngleL{\stepAngle*\selSector}
\pgfmathsetmacro\selAngleU{\selAngleL+\stepAngle}
\pgfmathsetmacro\selRadiusL{\baseR+\stepR*\selTrack}
\pgfmathsetmacro\selRadiusU{\selRadiusL+\stepR}

%% the drawing
\ifnum\selTrack>-1
  \fill[hdd sel track, even odd rule]
    circle [radius=\selRadiusU] circle [radius=\selRadiusL];
\fi
\ifnum\selSector>-1
  \fill[hdd sel sector, ring segment=\selAngleL\selAngleU\baseR\maxR];
\fi
\ifnum\selTrack>-1 \ifnum\selSector>-1
  \fill[hdd sel block,  ring segment=\selAngleL\selAngleU\selRadiusL\selRadiusU];
\fi                \fi

%% borders on top
\foreach \track in {0, ..., \numTracks}
  \draw[hdd border] (0,0) circle[radius=\baseR+\track*\stepR];
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \sectors in {1, ..., \numSectors}
  \draw[hdd border] (\i*\stepAngle:\baseR) -- (\i*\stepAngle:\maxR);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I made the circle from the outside in for the purpose of maintaining the "real" behaviour for the disk, but I don't really need it, I can just use it as it is. As the issue with alignment is resolved, I will mark it as solved. I thought that the macros may round the numbers, but I didn't know that they convert it to `pt`.

Comment: One more small question, why use `\newcommand*` instead of `\def`. Does it have any advantages or is it just a choice?

Comment: `\def` is a TeX primitive which has no security and will let you break something that already exists without warning. `\newcommand`, when used, verifies if what you try to create already exists, and warns you.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks, I will switch to `\newcommand` in my further endeavours.